# Could you help me please: is it correct to say 'your dream job is closer than you think'

Tags: single-word-requests

I live in Holland. On my LinkedIn account a Dutch ad from LinkedIn keeps popping up saying 'your dream job is closer than you think'. Is this correct or should it be 'your dream job is nearer than you think'? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tell us what a dictionary told you about "close" and "near".

Comment: "close" and "near" are pretty much synonymous, but as a native US English speaker I would say that "closer" sounds more natural/common to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close and near are very similar in meaning,  Your (or their choice) is grammatically OK. It is an ad!  They want takers. So terms like at hand and near are to encourage you to consider and/or apply for same.

**close**  [Being near in space or time](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/close)
**near**   [To, at, or within a short distance or interval in space or time](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/near)

**close at hand**

> 1. Nearby; physically within one's reach.

**just around the corner**

> BRITISH COMMON If something is just around the corner or just round
>   the corner, it is going to happen very soon

After responding you may say *cheers*, or *close but no cigar*!

Comment: Thank you. I was confused because of the comparative degree of close followed by 'than you think'. Is it grammatically correct? Which one is better: Your dream job is closer than you think or closerby than you think or just around the corner (without the comparative degree of close)?

Comment: "within reach" is another common way of telling someone that they can get actually something better with the right effort or help

Comment: Karen,  I would just "closer than you think"  if you mean to say "you can get it almost now" , but if you mean "after you take our 3 month program - or particularly if it is a 9 month program -  "just around the corner" would imply a some effort ..  around the corner to me is a season or two a way.